# How to use precompiled handlebars template in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have precompiled my handlebars template using [ember-precompile npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-precompile)

But i don't know how to use my precompiled template in order to render it ? How to get my app context ?
there is so many examples that didn't work or it's oudated :/

I am working on EmberJS [TodoMVC Example](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/emberjs/)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I am not sure which tutorial you are following exactly, but nowadays you are encouraged to create Ember applications via the ember-cli command line tool. This creates a full build pipeline for you which includes a handlebars precompiler. The github-repo for node-ember-precompile itself states that:  _New projects should use ember-cli. This package is available for legacy reasons, but is no longer being actively maintained._

Comment: Why making live so complicated when you can just use ember-cli and downgrade the ember versions if your purpose is to learn an old EmberJs version. My advise is to fallow any TO-DO MVC ember tutorial that is above EMBER 2.0 since a lot things before this one are getting deprecated.